# Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, gmaven-plugin, groovy-eclipse

While importing a Maven project to my Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) I faced a folloing error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.gmaven:groovy-maven-plugin:2.0:execute ...    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

What can be a reason of this and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can be a reason of this and how to fix it ?

Have a look at the [official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html), which explains the reason and possible workarounds quite well.